# Adding a darkmode stylesheet to localStorage with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, hyperlink, attr

So, I know right off the bat that using a separate stylesheet for darkmode is already a whacky way to go, but here is my situation:

I have an input trigger which, when .prop("checked", true), toggles the darkmode.css over the styles.css and when .prop("checked", false), removes this and you just have the standard 'light mode' styles.

What I want to achieve is, if .prop("checked", true) on the homepage, and I click on to another page, for example "About Us", I want to maintain that .prop("checked", true) and keep the dark mode.

`<input type="checkbox" id="darkmodeToggle" class="darkmode"></input>`

```
$("#darkmodeToggle").click(function() {
  if ($("#darkmodeToggle").prop("checked", true)) {
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/darkmode.css'}).appendTo('body');
  } else if ($("#darkmodeToggle").prop("checked", false)) {
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/styles.css'}).appendTo('body');
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/about.styles.css'}).appendTo('body');
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/operations.styles.css'}).appendTo('body');
  }});
```

Comment: you can switch by replacing the href !! without append it !!

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to get and set items. You can then do a check to see if the value is true/false at its basic usage.

Nothing really needed with jQuery.
Also, using `prop("checked", true)` sets the value. Even if it's in an `if` statement.
So all you need to do is get the Boolean value by `prop("checked")` this will return ether false or true.

Or before jQuery 1.6 something like:
`.attr('checked','checked')`

```
<label>Dark mode?
  <input type="checkbox" id="darkmodeToggle" class="darkmode"/>
</label>

var darkModeToggle = $("#darkmodeToggle");

$(function($) {
    if(!localStorage.getItem('darkmode')) {
    console.log('Setting darkmode on first visit')
        localStorage.setItem('darkmode', false)
  }
})

darkModeToggle.click(function() {
  
  if (darkModeToggle.prop("checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem('darkmode', true);
    
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/darkmode.css'}).appendTo('body');
  } else if (!darkModeToggle.prop("checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem('darkmode', false);
    
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/styles.css'}).appendTo('body');
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/about.styles.css'}).appendTo('body');
    $("<link>").attr({'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'styles/operations.styles.css'}).appendTo('body');
  }
  });
```